# $GL_n$($ℂ$) acts on the set $Mat_n$(ℂ) by conjugation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, linear-transformations, group-actions

I was studying Linear algebra, mainly  group actions on matrices of real entries but I read a statement regarding matrices of complex entries and I don't know why its true:

> Almost every $GL_n$($ℂ$)-orbit intersects the set of diagonal matrices in a non empty finite set.

I was having trouble figuring this out for $n$ dimension so i started with simpler case $n$=$2$,  If I work on orbit set containing rank two matrices for instance, they definitely intersect with diagonal matrices ( which are invertible) but still the possibilities of the matrices in the intersection is infinite , how come it says finite ? I will be grateful if someone explains this to me , I am still exploring this subject.

Comment: All the matrices in a single orbit have the same collection of eigenvalues.

Comment: This statement is a very complicated way to say that almost every matrix is diagonalizable, and that a diagonalizable matrix is similar to a finite number of diagonal matrices (which is quite easy to prove).

Comment: The set of rank $2$ matrices is not a $GL(\Bbb C)$-orbit. It is closed under the action by $GL(\Bbb C)$, but there is no single element $A$ such that each rank $2$ matrix is of the form $SAS^{-1}$ for some $S \in GL$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Isn't rank preserved under conjugation action? secondly if rank 2 matrices is not a $G$-orbit then what are the other orbits ?

Comment: @mulaan_20 It is, which is why I say that the set of rank $2$ matrices is closed under the group action. However, that is not enough for this set to satisfy the definition of an "orbit".

Comment: @BenGrossmann The set of rank 2 matrices is closed under this action? how did you conclude that?

Comment: @mulaan_20 It's a consequence of the fact that rank is preserved under conjugation.